# Событие в свойстве объекта

Tags: canvas, html, javascript

Выдержка из html-кода:

```
  <body onload="graf()">
    <canvas id="first" width="800" height="800" style='position:absolute;top:50px;left:30px'></canvas>
    <canvas id="second" width="800" height="800" style='position:absolute;top:50px;left:30px'></canvas>
  </body>
```

Выдержка из js-кода:

```
function graf(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById('first');
      h = canvas.height;
      w = canvas.width;
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      pie();

      histogram();
      diagram();

    }

    function DoTheThing (){

    }

    function pie(){
      var canvas = document.getElementById('second').onMouseOver = DoTheThing();
      **h = canvas.height;**
      w = canvas.width;
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
```

Звездочками выделена строка, на которую GoogleChrome ругается:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому-что нельзя так объявлять в js переменные, надо так:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('second');
canvas.onmouseover=DoTheThing; //тут тоже были ошибки, свойство называется onmouseover, handler объявляется без скобочек, иначе вы хэндлером объявляете результат выполнения DoTheThing;
```

если бы вы написали

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('second').onmouseover = DoTheThing;
```

то в canvas попала бы функция DoTheThing, а не canvas.

а если бы вы написали

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('click',DoTheThing);
```

то в canvas попало бы undefined, т.е. функция addEventListener ничего не возвращает (в отличии например от функции on() в jquery, которая возвращает обратно коллекцию:

```
var canvas = $('#second').on('mouseover',DoTheThing);
```

тут в canvas был бы объект jQuery созданный из селектора '#second'

Comment: не забудьте написать var перед w и h, или объявить их через запятую
примерно так:

    var canvas = document.getElementById('first'),
      h = canvas.height,
      w = canvas.width,
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');